# Cannot convert type Observable<Object> to type Observable<CategoriesData>

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I am using ASP.NET Core + Angular 2 template in Visual Studio 2015 to develop Angular 2 application.

On CategoryService, I am getting below error while trying to return an Observable.

[image]
Here is CategoryData:

```
export class CategoriesData {
public CategoryID: number;
public CategoryName: string;
public Description: string;
public Picture: string; }
```

Why am I getting this error? If I change return type from Observable to Observable, this error goes away. However, in that case I get return type as an Object instead of CategoryData in my component.

Below is the code in CategoryListComponent that is calling service.

[image]

Why is it not able to transfer data received from service into objCategories as CategoriesData? It says "undefined".

Please help!

Comment: Post the code too, not only an image for the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you haven't stated the type of data returned by the Http service call. You can typecast to state it.

```
getCategory(): Observable<CategoryData> {
  return this.http.get(this.url)
             .map(response => response.json() as CategoryData)
             .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.I tried to typecast in the map method of component but didn't work out. Visual Studio gives compile time error in the service itself. If I change return type to Observable<any> in service method then the error goes away.

Comment: Infact, I noticed that although I return Observable<any> the calling method in the component was receiving data into objCategories from service. But the main issue was that it was not displaying data in my Edit form, due to missing FormsModule import in the main module and it was not recognizing binding on the form. ( [(ngModel)]="objCategories.CategoryName" ).